# creating encrypted passwords in openfire MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, openfire, mcrypt, blowfish

Openfire stores encrypted passwords in a database using blowfish encryption.

http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/openfire/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/util/Blowfish.java is the java implementation for how encrypt / decrypt functions work in openfire.

My goal is to create new user entries in the database via PHP and MySQLI.  All of the variations I've tried have yielded results that don't match what already exists in the database.  For example:

`d3f499857b40ac45c41828ccaa5ee1f90b19ca4e0560d1e2dcf4a305f219a4a2342aa7364e9950db` is one of the encrypted passwords.  clear text, this is `stackoverflow`

I've tried a few variations:

```
echo mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, '1uY40SR771HkdDG', 'stackoverflow', MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, '12345678');
// result:  áë*sY¶nŸÉX_33ô
```

Another based on [mcrypt blowfish php slightly different results when compared to java and .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293928/mcrypt-blowfish-php-slightly-different-results-when-compared-to-java-and-net)

```
 $key = '1uY40SR771HkdDG';
 $pass = 'stackoverflow';
 $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size('blowfish', 'cbc'); // get block size
 $pkcs = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize); // get pkcs5 pad length
 $data.= str_repeat(chr($pkcs), $pkcs); // append pkcs5 padding to the data

 // encrypt and encode
 $res = base64_encode(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,$key, $pass, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT));
 echo $res;
 // result:  3WXKASjk35sI1+XJ7htOGw==
```

Any clever ideas, or any glaring problems?  I simply want to implement `Blowfish.encryptString()` as referenced in the first link in this question.

Comment: The most glaring problem is the fact that you are *encrypting* your passwords instead of *hashing* them. You shouldn't do that unless you **absolutely need** the password is its original form.

Comment: the XMPP protocol uses clear text to authenticate users.  that's why encrypt/decrypt is required in Openfire.  just trying to work with what i have ...

Comment: Have you got some test vectors for what it produces? i.e, key, iv, data and ciphertext combinations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a class I made, it encrypts and decrypts properly.

Note, you need to save / [pre/app]end the IV in order to reproduce results.

Some test vectors for the java code would be nice.

```
<?php

/**
 * Emulate OpenFire Blowfish Class
 */
class OpenFireBlowfish
{
    private $key;
    private $cipher;

    function __construct($pass)
    {
        $this->cipher = mcrypt_module_open('blowfish','','cbc','');
        $this->key = pack('H*',sha1($pass));
    }

    function encryptString($plaintext, $iv = '')
    {
        if ($iv == '') {
            $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($this->cipher));
        }
        else {
            $iv = pack("H*", $iv);
        }
        mcrypt_generic_init($this->cipher, $this->key, $iv);
        $bs = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size($this->cipher); // get block size
        $plaintext = mb_convert_encoding($plaintext,'UTF-16BE'); // set to 2 byte, network order
        $pkcs = $bs - (strlen($plaintext) % $bs); // get pkcs5 pad length
        $pkcs = str_repeat(chr($pkcs), $pkcs); // create padding string
        $plaintext = $plaintext.$pkcs; // append pkcs5 padding to the data
        $result = mcrypt_generic($this->cipher, $plaintext);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->cipher);
        return $iv.$result;
    }

    function decryptString($ciphertext)
    {
        $bs = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size($this->cipher); // get block size
        $iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($this->cipher);
        if ((strlen($ciphertext) % $bs) != 0) { // check string is proper size
            return false;
        }
        $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $iv_size); // retrieve IV
        $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, $iv_size);
        mcrypt_generic_init($this->cipher, $this->key, $iv);
        $result = mdecrypt_generic($this->cipher, $ciphertext); // decrypt
        $padding = ord(substr($result,-1)); // retrieve padding
        $result = substr($result,0,$padding * -1); // and remove it
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($this->cipher);
        return $result;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        mcrypt_module_close($this->cipher);
    }
}

$enckey = "1uY40SR771HkdDG";
$enciv = 'd3f499857b40ac45';
$javastring = 'd3f499857b40ac45c41828ccaa5ee1f90b19ca4e0560d1e2dcf4a305f219a4a2342aa7364e9950db';

$a = new OpenFireBlowfish($enckey);
$encstring = bin2hex($a->encryptString('stackoverflow',$enciv));
echo $encstring . "\n";
echo $a->decryptString(pack("H*", $encstring)) . "\n";

$b = new OpenFireBlowfish($enckey);
echo $b->decryptString(pack("H*", $javastring)) . "\n";
```

Comment: Ivo, thanks for this.  however, `d3f499857b40ac45c41828ccaa5ee1f90b19ca4e0560d1e2dcf4a305f219a4a2342aa7364e9950db` is `stackoverflow` encrypted in my example and this still doesn't decrypt that with the specified information.

Comment: What encoding is this using? It looks FAR to long to do stackoverflow

Comment: Note, it seems php fails to decrypt the data if it's not exactly right... if I tell it to decrypt something with the wrong key, it just sends back false :< Not sure why this is at the moment.

Comment: the example is straight from the contents in MySQL inserted by OpenFire.

Comment: OK, I amended my code... wasn't converting the string to unicode (theirs assumes two bytes per char, network order - UTF16BE is 2 bytes, big endian). I have confirmed that my code produces the same bytes to be encoded as in java, and it uses the same IV, the only thing I haven't checked is if the key is wrong or not. Hope it helps

Comment: HAH! Finally did it. You needed to pack the sha1 before using it as a key. My class now decrypts the example :)

Comment: I tried using the same code.. but the server does not decrypts in the proper format... Please Help!!!

Comment: @Ivo, How do you determine the value for `enciv`?

Comment: First 16 chars / 64 bits of the message.

Comment: @Ivo, What message do you mean? This is confusing, I'm still unable to get your algorithm to work. I have the key and the password but what what "message" do you mean that we needed for the `enciv`?

Answer (score 1):

Openfire's code prepends the CBCIV passed with the output string. It also using Unicode as the character set. These together may be the problem area.

I don't know enough about Blowfish's internals to help more, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, however to generate the same code as Openfire, you will need to add in two other items before the encrypted text.

- length of ciphertext
- CBCIV (initialization variable)

Read "public String decryptString(String sCipherText)" in java code, it's all there. Also check the docs on how to use CBCIV in PHP.