# Can I know the encryption algorithm used so that I could write my own sign-in code?

Tags: java, encryption, openfire

I don't know if this question is a valid one.

I am using the [registration.jar plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/registration/readme.html) provided by [igniterealtime](http://www.igniterealtime.org) to register users at *openfire* server .

Though the users get registered, the password that gets stored in the database is in the encrypted form. Is it possible to know which encryption algorithm has been used so that I could write my own *sign-in code* ?

Following is the snapshot of the result of the sql query `SELECT * FROM ofuser;` which shows the encrypted password.

[image]

The encrypted password : **f250d7a040859d66541e2ab4a83eb2225d4fff880f7d2506**

The actual password : **tester**

Comment: Only if it's a very poor encryption scheme.  If it's a good one you'd need to ask the developers.

Comment: What's the password for this test user that you've registered? Without knowing the password it's pretty much impossible to come up with a definite answer.

Comment: @Syon If the salt is difficult to determine(generation lies in the source which we can't find) then that won't help us much.

Comment: @Syon the password is **tester**

Comment: @SuhailGupta Please accept an answer to this question when you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's Blowfish, and isn't even a hash.

If you care about security, you may want to switch login providers or even products away from Openfire and its internal user provider.

> Blowfish has a 64-bit block size

I guess we have multiple blocks, though the password is somewhat short.

From cursory examination of the length of what is apparently a hash(not encryption) it appears to have 24 hexits, hence 24 nibbles, which equals 192 bits.

Unless the hash is truncated(then we don't know exactly), it [should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) Tiger, at the bottom of the page, for 192 bits.

Edit: No match for Tiger-192,3 or Tiger-192,4. Either it's salted or not Tiger.

I'll look for source.

Edit: It's probably Blowfish *encryption*, not hashing. Seems odd, but it's there, in

```
openfire_src_3_8_2.zip/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/DefaultUserProfider.java
```

> Passwords can be stored as plain text, or encrypted using Blowfish. The
>    encryption/decryption key is stored as the Openfire property passwordKey,
>    which is automatically created on first-time use. It's critical that the password key
>    not be changed once created, or existing passwords will be lost. By default
>    passwords will be stored encrypted. Plain-text password storage can be enabled
>    by setting the Openfire property `user.usePlainPassword` to `true`.

Comment: I must mention the password. It is **tester**

Comment: @hexafraction: +1 for finding this. -1000 to openfire for _Passwords can be stored as plain text_

Comment: @Syon I know! And no hashing without external user management!

Comment: @syon also -1000 to openfire for putting a fat chunk of processing logic in the JSP, which I found looking into the registration plugin.

Comment: @Syon "The encryption key is stored as the Jive property `passwordKey`" Worse. Even worse.

Comment: can we discuss here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35515/discussion-between-suhail-and-hexafraction

Comment: @SuhailGupta, There is a working solution on http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010834/632951 . You gotta translate it from PHP to Java though. Also see https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/50526

Answer (score 3):

Openfire is open source. Doesn't take much effort to investigate the problem yourself.

Starting [here](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/openfire/trunk/src/plugins/registration/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/plugin/RegistrationPlugin.java?hb=true) you can see that the registration plugin doesn't actually do the work of adding the user. It delegates to the [`UserManager`](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/~br=trunk/openfire/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/UserManager.java?hb=true). The `UserManager` delegates adding to an implementation of a [`UserProvider`](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/~br=trunk/openfire/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/UserProvider.java?r=13607&r=11291).

You need to figure out what user provider implementation you are using, and then have a look at how that handles passwords when it creates users. Just look at the implementation of

```
public User createUser(String username, String password, String name, String email)
       throws UserAlreadyExistsException;
```

And it should be obvious. Note that the password is in plaintext so any hashing/salting/encryption will be downstream from this point.

Edit:

Looks like its [`AuthFactory`](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/~br=trunk/openfire/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/auth/AuthFactory.java?r=11388);

```
    /**
     * Returns an encrypted version of the plain-text password. Encryption is performed
     * using the Blowfish algorithm. The encryption key is stored as the Jive property
     * "passwordKey". If the key is not present, it will be automatically generated.
     *
     * @param password the plain-text password.
     * @return the encrypted password.
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if encryption/decryption is not possible;
     *      for example, during setup mode.
     */
   public static String encryptPassword(String password) {
       if (password == null) {
           return null;
       }
       Blowfish cipher = getCipher();
       if (cipher == null) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
       return cipher.encryptString(password);
   }

   /**
     * Returns a decrypted version of the encrypted password. Encryption is performed
     * using the Blowfish algorithm. The encryption key is stored as the Jive property
     * "passwordKey". If the key is not present, it will be automatically generated.
     *
     * @param encryptedPassword the encrypted password.
     * @return the encrypted password.
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if encryption/decryption is not possible;
     *      for example, during setup mode.
     */
   public static String decryptPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
       if (encryptedPassword == null) {
           return null;
       }
       Blowfish cipher = getCipher();
       if (cipher == null) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
       return cipher.decryptString(encryptedPassword);
   }
```