# Register an openfire account via php

Tags: php, mysql, openfire, blowfish

I am trying to register an openfire account in mysql by php, but I can not encrypt password in blowfish format(openfire uses blowfish to encrypt password) that can be decrypted by openfire.
I tried this answer: [for openfire encrypts and decrypts in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705098/creating-encrypted-passwords-in-openfire-mysql-via-php)
But the password is encrypted by this way in php, can't be decrypted by openfire.

So please help me to find the solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to the OpenFire database directly it is possible to register accounts by making HTTP requests to the User Service plugin.

https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html

The plugin would need to be installed on OpenFire, but it is one of their standard plugins:

https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but just in case someone will be needing in the future.

In addition to JaredHatfield's comment. Yes you have to install Userservice plugin for Openfire to manage your openfire users by making an HTTP request per task.

I have written a php package for this. You can review if it fits the needs.

https://packagist.org/packages/jestillore/php-openfire-userservice