# How to modify OpenFire default password encryption algorithm?

Tags: php, xmpp, reverse-engineering, openfire, smack

By default, [OpenFire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfire) server encrypts passwords [using Blowfish encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705098/creating-encrypted-passwords-in-openfire-mysql-via-php/8010834#8010834) whereby the key is stored in the table [`ofProperty`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database-guide.html#ofProperty) `where propValue = 'passwordKey'`.

How can we **customize** this behavior?

How can we set OpenFire to use another encryption algorithm, or to **replace** the encryption algorithm with hashing instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the system properties to store plain password in openfire server and encrypt the password(as per your need) before sending the password.

### To change the system property: Go to

1. Server->Server Manager->System Properties
2. Edit the property `user.usePlainPassword` and give the property value
   as `true`.

Comment: ​+1 This is working *in a way* however is there a setting that allows us to **replace** the openkey default encryption algorithm with something else like hashing instead? In other words, not having to write our own code in an "upper layer" before the password reaches OpenFire.

Comment: I think there is no option like that. I searched a lot for this, but no use.so we implemeted in this fashion.If you find a way don't forget to answer your question.thanks

Comment: Will tick this answer until a better one appears.